# Can I make Stata run lasso faster?

Tags: stata, lasso, computational-statistics, numerics

I am trying to run a lasso in Stata.
I have 1.5 million observations and 1700 variables.
Stata is running too slow.
I am in 36th grid after 4 days. And get slower ever grid.
I am using a 98GB Memory, of 256GB available.
Can I set alphas or grids or reduce my data (in order to make it faster) without change too much the results?

Comment: I’d start with trying different software. This benchmark suggests that R is often faster https://github.com/matthieugomez/benchmark-stata-r

Comment: Can you tell us what command you're using?

Comment: lasso linear y X1-X1700

Comment: In this specific case there's a good chance the `glmnet` package in R will be faster if you have enough memory -- it's written in Fortran, using quite a lot of computational tricks, and is pretty efficient.

Comment: As a general rule, before embarking on a calculation that potentially could take a long time (and unless you have a massive number of cores running in parallel, this one obviously will take some time) you should benchmark smaller versions of the problem so you can determine how it scales and project how long it's going to take. Assuming it will be too long, there are many strategies you could consider, such as sampling your observations, sampling your variables, doing a more guided search than a brute force grid search, doing it in the cloud, *etc.*

Comment: If I try to sample observations, should I standarize the sample or the full population?